# Sharepoint 2010 - jQuery CEWP only loading in Edit Mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I know that this problem has been FREQUENTLY reported.
I have tried most suggested steps but not succeded.

I am trying to remove the default columns that can't be hidden from a Calendar (All Day Event, Recurrence, Workspace) and it works while editing the Web Part AND when editing a calendar event, but NOT when creating or viewing a calendar event.

I am pointing towards `/sites/[mysite]/SiteAssets/WebAssets/index.html` in the Web Part

```html
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/sites/[mysite]/SiteAssets/WebAssets/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/sites/[mysite]/SiteAssets/WebAssets/main.js"></script>
```

```js
function MyCustomFunction() {
  alert('hello')
  $('nobr:contains("All Day Event")').closest('tr').hide();
  $('nobr:contains("Recurrence")').closest('tr').hide();
  $('nobr:contains("Workspace")').closest('tr').hide();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', MyCustomFunction);
});
```

Setting a timeout does not help as the main  function is never fired(ie, probably not loading scripts):

```
var myVar;

function MyCustomFunction() {
  alert('MyCustomFunction running')
  $('nobr:contains("All Day Event")').closest('tr').hide();
  $('nobr:contains("Recurrence")').closest('tr').hide();
  $('nobr:contains("Workspace")').closest('tr').hide();
}

function mainFunc() {
  alert('main running')
  myVar = setTimeout(MyCustomFunction, 3000);
}

mainFunc()
```

Solved:
You indeed need to create one web part per view, which I failed to realize.

Comment: try using setTimeout

Comment: @NegiRox Does not help, see edited post above.

Comment: there are three different form for each editform, view, create, have you put same function in all pages?

Comment: @NegiRox I don't believe so, care to explain how?